# When using typescript framework all sources are compiled in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, nestjs

I am used to have possibility to go to source code of framework when I am using it. So I tried to install nestjs which is written in typescript. After following the instructions on [how to](https://docs.nestjs.com) generate a new app I noticed that all the sources for that framework in `node_modules/@nestjs` are already compiled to javascript and it's impossible to view actual typescript source code.

Is there any way to enable view for source code of typescript packages?

Comment: You can check their source code https://github.com/nestjs/nest

Comment: yeah, I know that but I'd like to see them in my editor though

Comment: Downloading their code and opening in your IDE is the option :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't view the typescript in `node_modules` because when a typescript package is published, if a developer is publishing it properly, they are publishing the compiled JavaScript. The only Typescript that gets published should be the `d.ts` file for typings. To view the raw source code, find the project on GitHub. Otherwise, the compiled JavaScript is always available in `node_modules`.

Comment: I feared you would say that

Comment: @arthur.borisow Node is, at its heart, a JavaScript runtime, meaning the packages being used are JavaScript. The only Typescript runtime around is [Deno](https://deno.land/).